# Make text inside TextView fit the screen

Tags: java, android, android-layout, textview

I want the text inside my TextView to fit the screen. I need to implement something like this:

[image]

The letter 'A' needs to be at the center of the screen with height equal to the height of the device screen. I have created a Custom TextView for this as follows but that doesn't seem to work. What I mean by this is that my text (letter A) isn't fitting the height of the screen. I tried manually adjusting the text font size but that isn't the right way I guess. Can someone point out a better solution for this?

```
 package com.example;

 import android.content.Context;
 import android.content.res.TypedArray;

 import android.graphics.Paint;
 import android.graphics.Rect; 
 import android.util.AttributeSet; 
 import android.util.TypedValue;
 import android.widget.TextView;

 public class FontFitTextView extends TextView
  {
    private Paint mTestPaint;
    private float maxFontSize;
    private static final float MAX_FONT_SIZE_DEFAULT_VALUE = 20f;

   public FontFitTextView(Context context)
   {
      super(context);
      initialise(context, null);
   }

   public FontFitTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet)
   {
    super(context, attributeSet);
    initialise(context, attributeSet);
   }

public FontFitTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet, int defStyle)
{
    super(context, attributeSet, defStyle);
    initialise(context, attributeSet);
}

private void initialise(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet)
{
    if(attributeSet!=null)
    {
        TypedArray styledAttributes = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attributeSet, R.styleable.FontFitTextView);
        maxFontSize = styledAttributes.getDimension(R.styleable.FontFitTextView_maxFontSize, MAX_FONT_SIZE_DEFAULT_VALUE);
        styledAttributes.recycle();
    }
    else
    {
        maxFontSize = MAX_FONT_SIZE_DEFAULT_VALUE;
    }

    mTestPaint = new Paint();
    mTestPaint.set(this.getPaint());
    //max size defaults to the initially specified text size unless it is too small
}

private void refitText(String text, int textWidth, int textHeight)
{
    if (textWidth <= 0)
        return;
    int targetWidth = textWidth - this.getPaddingLeft() - this.getPaddingRight();
    int targetHeight = textHeight - this.getPaddingTop() - this.getPaddingBottom();
    float hi = maxFontSize;
    float lo = 2;
    final float threshold = 1f; // How close we have to be

    mTestPaint.set(this.getPaint());

    Rect bounds = new Rect();

    while ((hi - lo) > threshold)
    {
        float size = (hi + lo) / 2;
        mTestPaint.setTextSize(size);

        mTestPaint.getTextBounds(text, 0, text.length(), bounds);

        if (bounds.width() >= targetWidth || bounds.height() >= targetHeight)
            hi = size; // too big
        else
            lo = size; // too small

    }
    // Use lo so that we undershoot rather than overshoot
    this.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, lo);
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
{
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    int parentWidth = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
    int height = getMeasuredHeight();
    refitText(this.getText().toString(), parentWidth, height);
    this.setMeasuredDimension(parentWidth, height);
}

@Override
protected void onTextChanged(final CharSequence text, final int start, final int before, final int after)
{
    refitText(text.toString(), this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
}

@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh)
{
    if (w != oldw)
    {
        refitText(this.getText().toString(), w, h);
     }
   }
}
```

XML file

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:res-auto="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:id="@+id/home_Layout"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linear1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical">

    <com.example.FontFitTextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="1"
        android:textSize="80sp"
        res-auto:maxFontSize="55sp" />

</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: "_but that doesn't seem to work._" Could you elaborate on this?

Comment: I edited the question. basically i need to text inside the textview to  fit the height of the screen. At present it doesn't fit the device screen height

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try calling `super.onMeasure()` method at the end of the `onMeasure()` method with the updated width and height (parentWidth, height).

Comment: Hi Naresh, I tried that..but then I don't see the text on the screen. :(

Comment: Try adjusting the width and height value before you call the super method. This value which you pass to super method is the one that decides the width and height. the values which you had in parentWidth and height might be too small or too large. Try to investigate and research on it.

Comment: Hi, on debugging using Log statements in Android, i get parentWidth as 480 and height as 0

Comment: what values you get in "widthMeasureSpec" and "heightMeasureSpec"? what does it make to look like? Means does it fill the screen when you call super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);?

Comment: No it doesn't fill the screen. It appears as a normal text..btw values I got are widthMeasureSpec --> 1073742304 and heightMeasureSpec 1073742514 . THis is when I call super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec) at the end

Comment: Then i think the problem is not in textView. It is still occupying the entire screen. Try to set Text size as "heightMeasureSpec" in px units. 

this.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, heightMeasureSpec);

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45546/discussion-between-parth-doshi-and-naresh-r)

Comment: I sort of found out a solution. But since the width of each character varies you get some variation than you could probably expect.